# Delete pages from PDF

Tags: python, pypdf

I want to delete certain pages from a pdf file, When I try to delete the last page in my 15-pages pdf, the program deletes the first page instead.

```
def delete_page():
    file1 = input("Enter the file's name: => example.pdf: ")
    file1_reader = open(file1, 'rb')
    file1_pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file1_reader)
    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    pages_to_delete = [15, 14]
    

    for page_num in  range(1, file1_pdf_reader.numPages):
        if page_num not in pages_to_delete:
            pdf_writer.addPage(file1_pdf_reader.getPage(page_num))
        

    output = open(file1.split('.')[0] + '_modifed' + '.pdf', 'wb')
    pdf_writer.write(output)

    file1_reader.close()
    output.close()        
    

delete_page()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pdf pages is indexed from [0, pdf.numPages), then to remove the last 2 pages, you will need use [13, 14].

When you use a number granter then 14, the lib trunc the value with numPages.

page % numPages = 15 % 15 = 0 = first page

Changes:

from: range(1, file1_pdf_reader.numPages)
to: range(file1_pdf_reader.numPages)

from: pages_to_delete = [15, 14]
to: pages_to_delete = [13, 14]